# How can I add event in apex chart js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts, apexcharts

I am developing an vertical bar chart using apex chart. But I can't set specific with to single bars and How can I add event handler to this. Suppose when click on one button, it will show one type of data, when click on another button, it will show one type of data.[image: image to using apex chart]

I tried to develop a dynamic bar chart and I am expecting to make it dynamic according to selected event

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the chart object in the options object which has the events you want to capture like the following:

```
   chart: {
      events: {
         click: function (event, chartContext, config) {
          console.log('mouse move');
        }
    }
```

For more details about the events: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/